# Remove Escaped character from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

How can the `&` be shown inside the XML field?

```
DECLARE @xml   XML

SET @xml = (SELECT 'test&test' AS xml_entity 
            FOR XML PATH('xml_merge'),TYPE)

SELECT @xml
```

The result is showing a `&amp;`

```
<xml_merge>   <xml_entity>test&amp;test</xml_entity> </xml_merge>
```

I also tried with `CDATA` tag but that didn't solve it:

```
DECLARE @xml   XML

SET @xml = (SELECT '<![CDATA[test&test]]>' AS xml_entity 
               FOR XML PATH('xml_merge'),TYPE)

SELECT @xml

<xml_merge>
  <xml_entity>&lt;![CDATA[test&amp;test]]&gt;</xml_entity>
</xml_merge>
```

How to handle this? I need to show the `&` instead of `&amp;`

Expected result

```
<xml_merge>   <xml_entity>test&test</xml_entity> </xml_merge>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampersand is a special character in XML. That's why it requires its entity `&amp;`

Please try the following SQL. It will show you that after the `SELECT ...` as a VARCHAR(), the entity is gone. It remains as such just inside the XML data type.

You can check it here: [2.4 Character Data and Markup](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax)

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML; 

SET @xml = (SELECT 'test & test' AS xml_entity 
               FOR XML PATH('xml_merge'),TYPE);

SELECT @xml;

SELECT @xml.value('(/xml_merge/xml_entity/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS xml_entity;
```

**Output**

```
xml_entity
test & test
```

Comment: @Bijujose, glad to hear that my answer clarified some XML peculiarity  for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an X/Y problem. You want invalid XML to be returned as XML. If you want the string value then you can pull it from the XML as a value and the escape characters will be removed, however, if you want invalid XML the way you outlined it above then you will have to convert the XML to a string and then replace the escapes.

```
DECLARE @xml   XML

SET @xml = (SELECT 'test&test' AS xml_entity 
            FOR XML PATH('xml_merge'),TYPE)

SELECT @xml


DECLARE @XmlBlob NVARCHAR(MAX)=CAST(@Xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT REPLACE(@XmlBlob,'&amp;','&')
```

> <xml_merge><xml_entity>test&test</xml_entity></xml_merge>